# System Information broke after upgrading python to 3.10

Tags: 20.04, python

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. When you login with putty it usually display your system information like this example

```
System information as of Mon May 30 06:16:35 UTC 2022

  System load:  0.55              Processes:           96
  Usage of /:   8.1% of 68.74GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 55%               IP address for eth0: 198.xx.xxx.xxx
  Swap usage:   0%
```

But when I upgraded python to 3.10 it no longer shows system information upon login. I tried manually running `landscape-sysinfo` but gave error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo", line 22, in <module>
    run(sys.argv[1:], reactor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 115, in run
    for plugin in config.get_plugins():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 69, in get_plugins
    return [namedClass("landscape.sysinfo.%s.%s"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/deployment.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
    return [namedClass("landscape.sysinfo.%s.%s"
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 173, in namedObject
    module = namedModule('.'.join(classSplit[:-1]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/python/reflect.py", line 159, in namedModule
    topLevel = __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/network.py", line 4, in <module>
    from netifaces import AF_INET, AF_INET6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'
```

so I tried to reinstall netifaces but it says it already installed the newest version. Is there any fix to this? I want to display system information again when logging with putty

Comment: Many Ubuntu tools rely on python3, and that is the *specific* version the release came with. If you change the *default* python3, you'll find many of the tools no longer operate, worse is that some will operate incorrectly meaning you'll get data corruption.  You should **not** change the default python3 version on a Ubuntu system, esp. if your data matters to you.

Comment: Reinstall ubuntu and never upgrade the default python version. If you need python3.10, use virtual environments or anaconda instead.